# Can I get a Jenkins trigger to run every first week day of every month?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, cron

My goal is to trigger a report every first weekday of the month at 7AM (7/1/15,8/3/15,9/1/15, etc.)

I am using the following cron expression: **H 7 1-3/3 * 1-5**

It runs on July 1, but it is not scheduled next to run on August 3, but on September 1. How can I get it to run on the first weekday of every month?

I am using the following help guide:

**MINUTE**  Minutes within the hour (0–59)
**HOUR**    The hour of the day (0–23)
**DOM**     The day of the month (1–31)
**MONTH**   The month (1–12)
**DOW**     The day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.

To specify multiple values for one field, the following operators are available. In the order of precedence,

- The * specifies all valid values
- M-N specifies a range of values
- M-N/X or */X steps by intervals of X through the specified range or whole valid range
- A,B,...,Z enumerates multiple values

To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First weekday of the month rules:

- If today is a Monday, then the job should be run if today is also the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd of the month
- If today is a Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, or Friday, then the job should be run if today is also the 1st of the month

The following cron expressions should do the job:

```
H 7 1-3 * 1
H 7 1 * 2
H 7 1 * 3
H 7 1 * 4
H 7 1 * 5
# Would last have run at Wednesday, July 1, 2015 7:00:02 AM EEST; would next run at Monday, August 3, 2015 7:00:02 AM EEST.
```

Beware, because of [this](http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/) article, you **can't** just use:

```
H 7 1-3 * 1
H 7 1 * 2-5
```

> The above doesn't work! Instead, the job is run on every weekday, twice on the 1st of the month, and maybe twice on the 2nd and 3rd of the month!

But I was not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 4):

This should work just fine:

```
H 7 1-3 * 1
H 7 1 * 2-5
```

The article to which the accepted answer is referred to is about crontab expressions. Jenkins cron expressions actually use **AND** for *DOM* and *DOW* (otherwise the solution from the accepted answer wouldn't work either)

Comment: Microsoft "Patch Tuesday" is the second Tuesday of the month. If the Month begins on Tuesday, then the second Tuesday is the 8th. If the month starts on Wednesday, the second Tuesday is the 14th. These extremes allow a nice Jenkins cron for Second Tuesday of the Month at midnight (to help others extend the same excellent reasoning Александр shared): `0 0 8-14 * 2 /usr/bin/patch-tuesday.sh`

Answer (score -3):

Here is the answer to your question, seems it can work

http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/

All the best